# Is there a shortcut command in Windows command prompt to get to the current user's home directory like there is in Linux?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, command-line

I am used to using

```
cd ~
```

to get right into my home directory. In Windows command prompt I have to do

```
cd Users\username
```

to get there. Is there a shortcut like the Linux one? It would be nice if I could get there by doing

```
cd username
```

Is something like this possible in Windows Vista?

Comment: In Unix, there's no need for the tilde.  `cd` with no arguments will change to your home directory.

Comment: there was a question like this here on su, can't find it.

Comment: @coneslayer i know but to move a file from one directory to another you use the tilde.

Comment: As simple as `cd %userprofile%`

Comment: You can use Windows Power Shell (on Win XP and later) which allows you to use ~ for the home directory. See also ----> 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can always put a `.bat` file somewhere in your `%PATH%` which does the path changing for you.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 219):

Yes, you can use `%HOMEPATH%`, and `%HOMEDRIVE%`. These contain the full path of the user's home directory (without drive letter), and the drive letter, respectively.

There are quite a few other useful variables available, such as `%OS%` (Operating System), or `%WINDIR%` (Windows system directory). See [Wikipedia: Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for a list.

---

*Notes*:

Actually, things are a bit complicated (as usual). There is also`%USERPROFILE%`, which *does* contain the drive letter, and is usually the same directory as `%HOMEPATH%` plus `%HOMEDRIVE%`.

The values of these variables, and which one is right for you, will depend on the Windows version and any changes by an administrator, as their values may be different (see e.g. the question [Difference between profile and home path](https://serverfault.com/questions/29948/difference-between-profile-and-home-path) ).

Comment: This is the most correct answer, in my opinion, because it does not rely on hard-coded paths and any wacky filesystem links that may be between them.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This saved my life!  After looking at a lot of other answers from different questions.  Again!  This worked for me and should be the marked as the answer for this question.

Comment: @MissLucy: I'm happy it helped you. As to accepting an answer: That's up to the OP to decide. You could add a comment to the question to alert them.

Comment: use %USERPROFILE% instead.

Comment: On my Windows 10 1809 `%HOMEPATH%` contains just a root directory `\ `. `%USERPROFILE%` is OK.

Comment: @pabouk: On my system (also Windows 10 V 1809), `%HOMEPATH%` works as described in the answer (full path, without drive letter). Maybe there is something unusual about your user profile/settings?

Comment: @sleske Yes, it looks like it is enforced from the company's domain. The worse part is that the path created from `%HOMEDRIVE%` (which you omitted in your answer) and `%HOMEPATH%` does not exist on my system. I will ask our technical support but this misconfiguration does not seem to seriously break anything.

Comment: @pabouk: Thanks for mentioning "HOMEDRIVE". I added it to my answer.

Comment: In an environment with roaming profiles this gets awkward pretty quickly. If I reboot my laptop and I'm on the work network, when I start up a PowerShell window, I end up at %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%. When my machine starts up away from my my work network, then its %USERPROFILE%. This is really frustrating to (cross-platform) tools that want to put dot-files (and directories!) into your home directory. In reality, the application ought to be more nuenced so that things like cache dirs etc (big stuff) use %LOCALAPPDATA% etc.). Roaming profile stuff is horrible for users that can't opt out of it.

Answer (score 25):

Two other options both of which can be added to a script and auto-executed in a similar manner to BillP3rd's answer.

It's two more characters but...

```
SET ~=%HOMEPATH%    
CD %~%
```

or...

```
CD %~%\Desktop
```

---

Or...

```
doskey ~=cd %homepath%
~
```

Of course you can't use this `~` in paths but as a quick "jump to my home dir" typing `~` <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pretty quick.

Comment: Are you kidding me with the doskey thing??? I now have a single char shortcut to any folder I feel like cd into. This should be #1 answer.

Comment: Note that without `%HOMEDRIVE%` this doesn't work if your not on the same drive as where your `%HOMEPATH%` is located. it should always be `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

Answer (score 14):

[sleske's answer](https://superuser.com/a/168719/37845) is almost exactly right, but it doesn't always work.

If your home directory is on a network share setup as a mapped drive, run the following regardless of the drive of the current directory:

```
cd /D %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```

The `/D` switch is necessary to allow `cd` to change drives.

Comment: `doskey ~=cd /D %HOME%`  Usage: press `~` then enter at the command prompt and you're teleported to the C: drive in your home dir.

Comment: For anyone else curious, Marcello's command uses `doskey`, a command builtin to Windows (and MS-DOS before it, all the way back to 1991 apparently), and creates a macro named `~` to run something like what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: (Although I forgot to mention it, I don't claim any merit for that command: I (re)discovered it via other answers. I simply hadn't found that exact line mentioned elsewhere so I posted it as a bookmark for my future self :) )

Answer (score 12):

I created a `.cmd` file in a directory in my `PATH` and named it `cd~.cmd`. Its contents are:

```bat
@cd %HOMEPATH%
```

I can type `cd~` from anywhere to get to my home directory, though it's not the same as `cd ~` (note the missing space), but is close enough for me.

Comment: Most clever answer. Combining yours with [this answer by Kenny Evitt](http://superuser.com/a/790844/401935) gives the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these solutions will enable tab autocomplete to fill out a longer path.  It chooses from the root directory `C:\`, for me anyway.

Answer (score 6):

#### Is there a shortcut for `C:\Users\<current user>\`?

There is no direct shortcut.

There are a couple of different solutions (see below).

1. Use an environment variable together with `cd` or `cd /d`
2. Use `subst` or `net use` to creating a mapping to another drive letter.
3. Install `cygwin` and use `bash`
4. Use `powershell` - powershell supports `~`

The last solution is probably the simplest if you are prepared to use `powershell` instead of `cmd`.

---

#### Solution 1: Use an environment variable together with `cd` or `cd /d`

If you want to change to this directory on a regular basis then run the following command:

```
setx DOCS %USERPROFILE%
```

This will permanently set the environment variable `DOCS`, but in order to use use it you need to first start a new `cmd` shell, then the variable is defined and ready to use:

```
F:\test>echo %DOCS%
C:\Users\DavidPostill\
```

To change directory from any location use the following command:

```
cd /d %DOCS%
```

If you are already on drive `c:` you can just use:

```
cd %DOCS%
```

Create a batch file (`docs.cmd`) and put it somewhere in your `PATH`.

**docs.cmd:**

```
@echo off
cd /d %DOCS%
```

You can then just type `docs` regardless of your current location and it will take you to `C:\Users\<current user>`

---

#### Solution 2: Use `subst` or `net use` to creating a mapping to another drive letter.

You can use `subst`:

```
subst x: %USERPROFILE%
```

And then

```
x:
```

Unfortunately drive mappings do not persist across reboots.

`net use` will persist across reboots, for example:

```
net use x: "\\computerName\c$\pathName" /persistent:yes
```

See the answers in [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots) for detailed instructions.

---

#### Solution 3: Install `cygwin` and use `bash`

You could consider installing [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/):

> Cygwin is:
>
> - a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Once you have installed cygwin you can run `bash` in a cygwin terminal and set the bash environment variable `HOME` as appropriate.

Alternatives to cygwin include [msys (MingW)](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys):

> MSYS is a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present. It is intended to supplement MinGW and the deficiencies of the cmd shell.

And [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/):

> Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line. *NIX users should feel right at home, as the BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX environments.

---

#### Solution 4: Use `powershell`

As pointed out in a comment on another question by [SBI](https://superuser.com/users/202976/sbi) powershell supports `~` and you can just type:

```
cd ~
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cd](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) - Change Directory - Select a Folder (and drive)
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).
- [subst](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html) - Substitute a drive letter for a network or local path.

Comment: If on Powershell there are two additional ways:

`cd $HOME` and
`cd $env:HOMEPATH`

Comment: @DavidPostill I may be misunderstanding the use of the word _"shortcut"_, but if not, your answer that there is no shortcut to `%UserProfile%` is factually inaccurate: `cd %UserProfile%`.

Answer (score 3):

Dunno if its a feature of our work login script or a windows default, but I can use `cd %HOMEPATH%` to achieve that, where `HOMEPATH` is an environment variable.

Comment: I see. It still takes a lot to write %HOMEPATH%. Also you can't auto-complete it. Is there a way I can make my username be equal to %HOMEPATH% by making a new command in cmd.exe?

Answer (score 2):

I think everybody missed the main point: the purpose of cd ~ is to use the least number of keystrokes and not awkward percents, dollars, or tildes... and god forbid "cd %HOMEPATH%" or "cd %HOME%"

Since long time ago, I have with a c:\Tools\bats directory where I put my optimized minimum typing script named.... cdd.bat..

So, why cdd.bat ? Why not home.bat or h.bat ?
Simple: with home or h, you would have a little extra right hand shift movement to hit 'h','o','m' and still have to move the left hand once to hit 'e' while right hand waits to hit enter and also important, that makes 5 keystrokes for home, and only two for 'h' BUT right hand needs to shift around a bit... which I will trade off.
With 'h', there is a little shift move of the entire right forearm to hit 'h' then 'enter'... which I will also trade off

With 'cdd', though, both my hands already resting on the optimal keyboard place so there is no extra movement from either. Gets me 4 keystrokes while the first three are a quick succession.

You have to try and pay attention on a day to day bases to see the benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all user's commmand prompts to start in their "home" directory, create the following registry key as an Expandable String Value (sans quotes, of course):

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun : "cd /d %USERPROFILE%"
```

If you want only *your* command prompts to do it:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun : "cd /d %USERPROFILE%"
```

I make it a practice to keep a `C:\Scripts` folder in which I keep an `autoexec.bat` file which I invoke via this key.

Comment: Watch out, this will break bower and npm (and Visual Studio)...

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a long since done question, but just for the record.  Install [`clink`](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/), this extends your command prompt in so many ways.  Yes it it heavier then the above solutions but it makes the cmd window behave so much better.

Comment: clink == powerful Bash-style command line editing for cmd.exe

Comment: Right, and the whole point is that ~ resolves to the User\{user} directory.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has really become "all about the GUI", so in your case, I'd just get the tools you want instead of trying to "bend" the system to your will. The [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) tools are an excellent little collection of some of the most widely used GNU tools and I highly recommend it if you're a nix fan on Win.

Answer (score 0):

I used a better terminal ([cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder)) for this purpose.
It has built in aliases and its very easy to use.
Just read the documentation about Aliases [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#aliases).

Answer (score 0):

I write a `home.bat` with content `set home="ur/home/path"&c:&cd %home%` and save it to any folder *declare in environment variables* if not in Cdrive edit content `home.bat`.
So that u can use **home** as command in anywhere by cmd.
Also edit variable *home* to quick-set home-path in current session ,quite convenient.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).