# cd (change directory) to my home directory on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a short cut command in Windows command prompt to get to the current users home directory like there is in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/168714/is-there-a-short-cut-command-in-windows-command-prompt-to-get-to-the-current-use)

Any short way to cd to the user specific directories in the command prompt. Like for e.g. in linux shell (debian based) we do a `cd ~` and it instantly takes to the current logged user's directory `/home/<username>`. Anything to this effect on windows?

ps: currently trying to do this on xp machines. If it differs for other machines, mention that too.

Comment: Actually, on Unix just `cd` with no arguments will take you to your home directory.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The environment variable is called [`%userprofile%`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples_from_Microsoft_Windows) , which should work on most NT or newer machines.

As per James' comment if you're on another drive you would need to do `cd /D %userprofile%`, else `cd %userprofile%` will do.

Comment: If you are on a different drive to your user profile it wont change it for you, so you need to add the switch `/D` to `cd` to do this.

Comment: `cd %homepath%` seems to work, too

Comment: cd ~ will work fine on windows powershell, if you experience unsupported commands make sure you are using the correct terminal