# cmd equivalent to "cd ~" to change to C:\Users\<current user>\Documents\

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

I have to switch to Windows for the duration of a project.

I have only just started, and I already dislike using `cmd`.

Is there a shortcut for `C:\Users\<current user>\Documents\` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a shortcut command in Windows command prompt to get to the current users home directory like there is in Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/168714/is-there-a-shortcut-command-in-windows-command-prompt-to-get-to-the-current-user), or of [cd (change directory) to my home directory on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/347727/cd-change-directory-to-my-home-directory-on-windows)

Comment: @Hastur The dupes don't address the "Documents" part of the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill The title is the same(you may think to change it), the answers rely on `%USERPROFILE%`, `%HOMEPATH%` setting a variable, doing a bat file, using MinGW... as in the others. Can we do other questions about how to change into the Desktop directory and so on? I hate to close questions it's against my nature :-)

Comment: @Hastur Yes, I will change the title. Also my answer provides some other suggestions that aren't covered in the dupes ...

Comment: @DavidPostill You can post in the other one too (55k view in 5 years): I can state it's a good audience that deserves a complete more answer. ;-)

Comment: Have you considered using powershell instead of cmd? Or doesn't that float for some other reason? Because `cd ~` in powershell works just like under unix.

Comment: @SBI Nice one. You need `cd ~/documents` for the OPs particular case. Adding to my answer.

Comment: @SBI I did not know that. However, to run Intel's icl, I require a shortcut to ``C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /K ""C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.2.180\windows\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" ia32 vs2015"``. Does powershell provide the necessary options as well?

Comment: @User1291 I honestly don't know, you'd have to try. The trickyness with the powershell "unix-like" commands is that they're really just aliases for Powershell commands (hence the result when you try `man cd` showing the manpage for `set-location`). So I guess you could just give it a shot.

Comment: @User1291 You can run shortcuts from powershell. See [PowerShell trick : Execute .lnk file](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30018.powershell-trick-execute-lnk-file.aspx)

Comment: @User1291 PowerShell is vastly superior to cmd.exe (and bash honestly but that's a different topic), so you really, *really* want to use it (particularly if you know Bash and co - there are aliases for most of its commands). If you have existing code, you can just call `cmd /c` to execute some commands in that one which works for most circumstances (if environment variables are set in the child process you'll have to make sure to transfer them back afterwards - that's ugly but there's code somewhere on SO for that too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut for `C:\Users\<current user>\Documents\`?

There is no direct shortcut.

There are a couple of different solutions (see below).

1. Use an environment variable together with `cd` or `cd /d`
2. Use `subst` or `net use` to creating a mapping to another drive letter.
3. Install `cygwin` and use `bash`
4. Use `powershell` - powershell supports `~`

The last solution is probably the simplest if you are prepared to use `powershell` instead of `cmd`.

---

#### Solution 1: Use an environment variable together with `cd` or `cd /d`

If you want to change to this directory on a regular basis then run the following command:

```
setx DOCS %USERPROFILE%\Documents
```

This will permanently set the environment variable `DOCS`, but in order to use use it you need to first start a new `cmd` shell, then the variable is defined and ready to use:

```
F:\test>echo %DOCS%
C:\Users\DavidPostill\Documents
```

To change directory from any location use the following command:

```
cd /d %DOCS%
```

If you are already on drive `c:` you can just use:

```
cd %DOCS%
```

Create a batch file (`docs.cmd`) and put it somewhere in your `PATH`.

**docs.cmd:**

```
@echo off
cd /d %DOCS%
```

You can then just type `docs` regardless of your current location and it will take you to `C:\Users\<current user>\Documents\`

---

#### Solution 2: Use `subst` or `net use` to creating a mapping to another drive letter.

You can use `subst`:

```
subst x: %USERPROFILE%\Documents
```

And then

```
x:
```

Unfortunately drive mappings do not persist across reboots.

`net use` will persist across reboots, for example:

```
net use x: "\\computerName\c$\pathName" /persistent:yes
```

See the answers in [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots) for detailed instructions.

---

#### Solution 3: Install `cygwin` and use `bash`

> Only just started, already hate cmd

You could consider installing [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/):

> Cygwin is:
>
> - a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Once you have installed cygwin you can run `bash` in a cygwin terminal.

Alternatives to cygwin include [msys (MingW)](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys):

> MSYS is a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present. It is intended to supplement MinGW and the deficiencies of the cmd shell.

And [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/):

> Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line. *NIX users should feel right at home, as the BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX environments.

---

#### Solution 4: Use `powershell`

As pointed out in a comment by [SBI](https://superuser.com/users/202976/sbi) powershell supports `~` and you can just type:

```
cd ~/documents
```

If you have strange characters in your user name (for example if your user name is an email address) then quote as follows:

```
cd "~/documents"
```

**But also I need to be able to run a shortcut!**

> However, to run Intel's icl, I require a shortcut to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /K ""C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.2.180\windows\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" ia32 vs2015"`.
>
> Does powershell provide the necessary options as well?

You can create a shortcut as normal to run the above command.

Then execute the shortcut from powershell, for example:

```
 Invoke-Item -Path C:\Users\Dex\Desktop\Notepad++.lnk
```

And:

```
 Start-Process -FilePath  C:\Users\DDhami\Desktop\Notepad++.lnk
```

Source [PowerShell trick : Execute .lnk file](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30018.powershell-trick-execute-lnk-file.aspx).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cd](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) - Change Directory - Select a Folder (and drive)
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).
- [subst](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html) - Substitute a drive letter for a network or local path.

Comment: You could also `subst` mount the directory as a volume.

Comment: @paradroid Yes, but `subst` does not persist if you reboot. There is a workaround for this (see [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](http://superuser.com/q/29072)), but it requires 3rd party software or registry changes.

Comment: Yes, but could alternatively mount it in a startup script (if that is not mentioned on that page)..

Comment: Ah, and there is also `net use` /persistent.  Not used that in years!

Comment: @DavidPostill The `~/documents` needs to be in double quotes like this: `cd "~/documents"`, otherwise it won't be expanded properly (for...reasons). The edit is too short for me to make.

Comment: @SBI Are you sure? I just tried it without and it worked. http://i.imgur.com/JLVKYKI.png

Comment: @DavidPostill Seems to be the reason, I just tried in a vm with a regular user name. It's astonishing I've never stumbled over that before.

Comment: Instead of cygwin for most purposes msys is enough. Git for windows also includes quite a few tools to make the environment more unixy, and they might be less obtrusive than cygwin

Comment: Power shell version is just like Linux.Microsoft created PowerShell because of the command prompt was still DOS

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 5: Doskey**

Not sure if you've been around since the dos days.. However, it's possible to overwrite command behavior using doskey macros.  It's quite fun actually and doesnt require you to install any 3rd party software.

Here's a good example:

```
doskey cd=if "$1" equ "~" ( cd /d %userprofile%\Documents ) ELSE ( cd $* )
```

And a winning screenshot to go with it.

[image]

Comment: You probably want to add a `/d` to the `cd %userprofile%\Documents` so it works even when on other drives.

Comment: There is another problems with this solution: `cd "WebCam Media"` returns `Media" ) was unexpected at this time.`.

Comment: The command is called `doskey`.This shows Windows still uses the DOS command prompt

Comment: @SuiciDoga Sorry, that's not correct. The command prompt just has *a lot* of compatibility features to make old batch files still run. `cmd.exe` is very much a Windows program, and is even 64-bit on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Note even though folder completion doesn't work with it due to double quotes. It will work with wildcards without double quotes. Also thanks @BenN

Answer (score 8):

%userprofile% works to get to the user's profile folder - this way you do not have to specify the drive letter.

i.e. instead of using `cd C:\%HOMEPATH%\Documents` you can just use `cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents`

Comment: That doesn't work if you are currently on another drive.

Comment: Which is easily fixed by using `cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\Documents"`, of course.

Comment: This should be main answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%HOMEPATH%`. It will take you to your home directory, just like the tilde does in linux. So to get to your desired location, the command is:

```
cd C:\%HOMEPATH%\Documents\
```

Comment: I suppose using `%HOMEPATH%` instead of `%USERPROFILE%` could be a good idea with domain accounts using Folder Redirection.

Comment: That doesn't work if you are currently on another drive

Comment: @DavidPostill `cd /d ...` ...

Comment: cd "..\Documents and Settings" does not run