# Create Link directory

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots)

I type the following command in order to create link between the Z:
directory to the `C:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\final_dir` directory

```
  Subst  Z: C:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\final_dir
```

The problem is that after reboot the Z: directory is deleted.

My question is: how do I fix that to get the Z: link directory to
persist after a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

`Z:` is a *drive*, not a directory.

To answer your question, `subst` drives are inherently transient.
You need to run that command every time you reboot.

You can do that by putting it in a `.bat` fil in the `Startup` directory.

Comment: Is it not the "[root directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory)?"

Comment: Every drive has a root directory - the `\ ` directory in the drive.  `Z:` is a drive; its root directory is `Z:\ `.