# How can I set a batch file to run when Windows XP starts up?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots)

I want to run a batch file after Windows XP starts up. How can I do that?

My `run.bat` file:

```
  subst Z: C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file
```

I put `run.bat` in the startup folder (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`) but the link isn’t created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](http://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots) - this question provides an answer to solve this exact problem without using batch files.

Comment: This looks similar to another question I just edited: http://superuser.com/questions/263545/how-can-i-make-a-vb-script-execute-every-time-windows-starts-up

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a batch file for this a simple registry trick makes the `subst` persist across reboots.

Wikipedia has how: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst#Persisting_across_reboots

Comment: can you have idea  in which dir I need to create the .bat file  in order to run the run.bat after win startup?

Comment: You could put the batch file anywhere and create a shortcut in the startup folder for it.  Don't put the batch file itself directly in there.

Comment: I did it but I get error about to open the .bat file did you sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `.bat` in the startup file

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User Name\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```