# How can I make a VB script execute every time Windows starts up?

Tags: windows-xp

My goal is to copy `INI.file` each time Windows XP is started up or rebooted.

The following VB script copies `INI.file` from a local directory to `C:\INI_DIR`.

I tried to copy the VB script to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, but it doesn't get activated. Is it not the right path? How can I make it execute on startup/reboot?

The script:

```
   Dim currDir 
   Const OverwriteExisting = True  

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

  currDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName) 




  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


  objFSO.CopyFile currDir  & "\INI.file" , "C:\INI_DIR" , OverwriteExisting


  ' Release the objFSO objects
    Set objFSO = Nothing


   ' Release the fso objects
   Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706267/launch-vbs-script-after-pc-startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the wrong path.  That's the login profile for the system account (Couldn't find any direct documentation, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) makes mention of that fact).  That's the account that system servers will run, but it won't run for interactive users.

The startup folder for your account is in:

```
c:\Documents And Settings\{Your User Name}\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Or if you want it to run for all logins, but it into:

```
c:\Documents And Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: Note that this runs on login, not startup. The key difference is that after login, you run in the security context of the logged-in user.

Comment: what's the diff , anyway I need to login ?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you...
Especially if you are not used to coding and would rather use a gui interface.

In-depth

How to Automate VBScripts to run at startup.

Step 1

- Click `Start -> Run -> cmd` or Click `search` and type `cmd`
- Press `enter`
- Type `assoc .vbs` in command prompt Which should print `.vbs=VBSFile`
- Type `ftype VBSFile` in command prompt
  which should print:

  `vbsfile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*`

So, now you know that your vbscript files open with WScript by default.

In command-prompt, type:

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe /s
```

If you do not see this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

Then you need to do the following, if the above is what you see, then you can skip and go to step 3:

Step 2

Go to:

- Start
- Run
- Type in:  `regedit`
- Select `regedit` press `enter` (or double-click regedit) and `allow the program to make changes to your computer`
- Navigate to:
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe` (If `WScript.exe` key does not exist, right-click `Applications` and `create new key`, rename it to WScript.exe)
- In the empty space on the right, where there are values, `right-click` and
  Choose `new`
- Select `String Value`
- Under `Name` where `New Value #1` is highlighted, `rename` by typing `(Standard)`
- Under `Data`, double click the empty value and enter the value you got from the previous step

  `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*`

Step 3

If you do not have `regedit` open,
Go to:

- Start
- Run
- Type in: `regedit`
- Select `app`, press enter and `allow the program to make changes to your computer`
- Else, if regedit is open, then:
- Navigate to:

  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- Right click the run folder
  in the empty space on the right, where there are values, right-click and choose `new`
- Select `Expandable String Value`
- Under Name where New Value #1 is highlighted, rename by typing your own name e.g. myscript
- under Data, double click the empty value and enter this
- Make sure its type is `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, i.e. an expanded string

  `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "C:\Users\me\myFolder\mySub-folder\myFile.vbs" "%1" %*`
- Restart your machine. Your vbs should run automatically

Notes:

make sure .VBS is added to the Path environment variable
if you want to use cscript instead, In step 2 type:

```
`reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cscript.exe /s`
```

...instead and proceed, taking note to replace WScript with cscript where relevant i.e. this query:

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cscript.exe /s
```

Should produce this result:

`(Standard)    REG_SZ`    `"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "%1" %*`
If your key and/or value is messed up you can always right-click the messed up item and delete it. If you however want to use the terminal, you can always follow: http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html
To check if WScript is one of the startup apps, press ctrl+alt+delete, choose the Task Manager, click on Startup. You should see Microsoft Windows Based Script Host listed.

Comment: Thanks "anon" - for future reference, link only answers are not generally helpful (even when to other Stack Exchange sites)

Answer (score 0):

Start > Run> `gpedit.msc` will open the Group Policy editor where you can set up scripts to run on user logon.