# Map folder as drive permanently in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

Lets say I need to map folder C:/D as drive D:

One can use SUBST command to map folder as drive in Windows.

```
SUBST d: C:/D
```

I am absolutely happy how SUBST does the work. So I set this command as a startup task using the task manager.

A problem here is that if I have a flash in a USB port while booting Windows, the flash is got mapped as D: and SUBST fails.

The question is how to make C:/D to be D: permanently. So other drives (especially flash drives) don't break this during startup.

P.S. I know I could set D: to be R: which is unlikely to conflict with other drives. But I would greatly appreciate another answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some posts here, apparently you can make it persistent with a registry modification:
[How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots)

Granted I haven't tried this myself...

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed using the "...\Session Manager\DOS Devices" registry entry solved the problem with early drive initialization.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this utility to solve the conflict. it is called USB Drive Letter Manager for Windows.

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The tool allows to set new usb letters. This could help for usb. But there could be not-USB-disks inserted too. I really would love a solution how to 'reserve' disk letter to use it. Some system policy maybe...