# Persitently map local folder to drive only for a single user profile

Tags: windows, windows-registry, user-accounts

In our setup we need to map a local folder as a drive to get rid of the username in the path.

We used "subst" to map the drive and everything was fine.

Now we are migrating to Windows 7 and company policies force use to use users without admin rights. To be able to change settings we got local admin accounts as well, but they lack network access and cannot be used for much else.

So as you may guess I do encounter a problem when running executables from my mapped drive "as Admin", since the admin account does not have the mapped drive.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots) solution, which works fine until someone else tries to use my machine. He will have my folder mapped as drive and not his folder.

So here is my question:

Is there a way to map a drive to a local folder permanently but only for a given user and not all users of the machine?