# Mount a folder as a external device

Tags: windows, mount, usb-storage

Is it possible to mount a folder so that windows recognize it as an external usb storage (like a memory card or usb stick)? Using Window 8.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Visual Subst](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html). It's a lightweight tool to generate virtual drives from directories.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It's not exactly what I'm looking for because that mounts it as a Drive. Was I need is something that simulates a ubs device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the batch command [`SUBST drive_letter: path`](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html)

```
SUBST Z: C:\path\to\source\folder
```

- Where `Z:` is your desired drive letter and `C:\path\to\source\folder` your source folder
- Make a batch file and place it in your autostart folder. Otherwise the [substitution is lost after every reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It's not exactly what I'm looking for because that mounts it as a Drive. Was I need is something that simulates a ubs device.