# Renaming volume created via "DOS Devices" registry key?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, subst

Following [the instructions in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots), I have created two drives that point to folders on an existing drive.  Everything works great.  The only problem is that they all have the same volume label.  When I try to rename the created drives, I get `The volume label is not valid. Please enter a valid volume label.`

So, is there a way around this error?  Perhaps another registry key for the volume label?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, clear custom label from the original drive.

Then create custom key and label for your drives, both original and virtual, at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\`.

For `E` drive:
[image: Custom label for E: drive]

For `O` drive:
[image: Custom label for O: drive]

Note `DriveIcons\E` and `DriveIcons\O` - the letters should match. Modify the `(Default)` keys and put drive names to value fields.

Reboot.

It should be noted that after doing this you cannot rename the original volume via Explorer. It will change the other volume labels back. It is easily undone though by removing the label again, no reboot required. However, if you want to rename the original you can follow the same procedure and create an entry in the registry

Comment: Flawless Victory!

Comment: It should be noted that after doing this you cannot rename the original volume via Explorer.  It will change the other volume labels back.  It is easily undone though by removing the label again, no reboot required.  However, if you want to rename the original you can follow the same procedure and create an entry in the registry.