# Rename OneDrive for Business folder in Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, onedrive

After installing Office 365, I have a new special folder in Explorer called "OneDrive - Company Name LLC".

I found a registry key at `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace` whose value matches that text (and it's the only match in the registry), and I confirmed previously that *deleting* it will remove the entry from Explorer, so I assumed I could rename it here.  However, it does not seem to work.  I changed the value and even rebooted, but the display value did not change.

**How can I rename my personal OneDrive folder?**

---

Background/reasoning:

I have synced a Sharepoint document library as a public share of sorts. It shows up as "Company Name LLC".  My *personal* OneDrive shows up as "OneDrive - Company Name LLC".  This has already led to confusion with some employees.  They thought they were putting files in a public space but were not.  Ideally it would be named something like "OneDrive - Personal Folders".

Comment: The name "OneDrive - Personal" is generally used for personal OneDrive folder with Microsoft account (hotmail.com, Outlook.com etc.). If your "personal" OneDrive here is still meaning for OneDrive for Business folder, it cannot be renamed to OneDrive - Personal folder. It uses Organization name by default.

Comment: My OneDrive (windows 10) is now displayed as "OneDrive - Personal" (changed overnight). Anyone knows how to remove the " - Personal"? Tried to edit the registry keys, to no avail! It reverts back to "OneDrive - Personal"!

Answer (score 12):

There are some good answers here, and since they're scattered I made this post to include the whole process and procedure in addition to what is missing.

**Process**

- Close OneDrive (step 1 below)
- Rename OneDrive folder (step 2 below)
- (optional) Move the OneDrive folder to the desired location (step 3 below)
- Modify the relevant registry keys (steps 4-5 below)
- Modify the configuration file (steps 6-8 below)

**Procedure**

1. Close OneDrive.
2. Rename the OneDrive folder.
3. (optional) Move the OneDrive folder to the desired location.
4. Open the registry (start menu >> search "regedit")
5. Modify the OneDrive folder or path in the following locations: (or follow @xoxox advice and search for "OneDrive - (company name)"

> In HKEY_CURRENT_USER (HKCU) (4 locations)
>
> > HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1\UserFolder
> > HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1\ScopeIdToMountPointPathCache\(`ID`)
> > HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1\Tenants\(`name`)\(`path`)
> > HKCU\Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\(`ID`)\MountPoint
>
> In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM) (2 locations)
>
> > HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Security Center\Provider\CBP\(`ID`)\NAMESPACE
> > HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager\OneDrive!(`ID`)\UserSyncRoots\(`SID`)

6. Open the following location: `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business1`
7. Locate the `(ID).ini` file (usually it's the 2nd file) and edit it (right click >> edit)
8. Locate the OneDrive path in the first line (in the value of the `libraryScope` parameter) and modify it to be as the new path. Then save the file.
9. Open OneDrive.

**Notes**

In step 5 above, some parameters are quoted (e.g. `(name)`, `(ID)`, `(path)`) - that means that these parameters are interchangeable, and there should be some value that is probably unique to your case.

**Reference**

[Changing your onedrive name in file explorer navigation](https://medium.com/@osaycanyousay/changing-your-onedrive-name-in-file-explorer-navigation-d854fd901198)

[How can I change default name of OneDrive for Business folder?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1966305-how-can-i-change-default-name-of-onedrive-for-business-folder)

Comment: This answer is great for changing the path to the folder, but unfortunately not the company name that appears in the Explorer sidebar (OneDrive resets it to the original one - also mentioned in my comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1323343/#comment2385888_1522952).) Also, in addition to the above mentioned keys, it is good practice to also change the value of the `OneDriveCommercial` environment variable to point to the new path, so that apps and scripts that depend on it, are not broken: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\OneDriveCommercial`

Comment: This answer works! Thank you! I did have to ensure that BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) is not running before I can rename the folder. And to be really careful, instead of just re-opening OneDrive, I restarted my computer.

Comment: It reverts to the old name (in explorer)

Comment: works like a charm, you are a saviour - I cannot believe that you cannot select a folder of your choice with the UI

Comment: I cannot change this value: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Security Center\Provider\CBP\(ID)\NAMESPACE`. will it cause an issue?
with the rest of the steps, your solution worked, it is syncing. however it recreates the old directory and the desktop content are still in here (not synced). anyone have updates on this?

Answer (score 11):

This is a **hacky**, but the only **working** solution:

1. First, close OneDrive: Click the icon in the taskbar, select `More...` then `Close OneDrive`
2. Next open Registry Explorer: Press `Win + R`, then type `regedit` and hit enter.
3. Press `Ctrl + F` to search for all occurrences of `OneDrive - <Company>` and replace these with the new desired name.
4. For all files in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive` (i.e., enter `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive` in the address bar) and subfolders, replace all occurrences of `OneDrive - <Company>` with the new desired name. (This can be achieved with Notepad++ by selecting `Search > Find in Files...` from the menu)
5. Rename your original `OneDrive - <Company>` folder to the new desired name.
6. Reopen OneDrive.
7. OneDrive might realize that the folder name has been change and will ask to set up the OneDrive folder again. Do not do this or else your work will be reverted!

<strike>**Consider voting for the Rename-OneDrive-Root-Folder feature on UserVoice:**</strike>

- https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913522-onedrive-on-windows/suggestions/37945567-allow-users-to-change-the-onedrive-folder-director
- https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913522-onedrive-on-windows/suggestions/8729746-allow-onedrive-for-business-folder-to-be-renamed

Comment: That was almost enough. Another thing is to change the path in the `libraryScope` parameter in `C:\Users\oze\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business1\<ID>.ini` where <ID> is the ID

Comment: I followed all the steps here and replaced all occurrences in the registry (Which included the ones in `HKCU` and a few in `HKLM` as well) and also in the config files. Then, I restarted Windows Explorer before reopening the OneDrive app. The Explorer did show the new name and did open the folder in the new location. However when I opened the OneDrive app, it changed back all the occurrences of my new name back to the old one (it didn't ask me to set up anything again, did everything silently). I cannot find my changed name in the registry anymore. I'm using OneDrive version 20.084.0426.0007.

Comment: However this did help me change the name of my destination folder for OneDrive, thanks! Upvoted! It should be sufficient to change all occurrences of the original path `C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive - Business name` for this purpose, there's no need to change anything else.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
mklink /J your_desired_name "OneDrive - Company Name LLC"
```

**Edit**: You should probably **first** `CD` to the home directory, e.g., `C:\Users\Me` (or whatever your home directory is) since that is the location of your `OneDrive - <Company>`.

Comment: Exactly what is the expected outcome of this? It created a junction, but there is no new entry in Explorer.

Comment: You may need to open CMD as administrator. And check if the link was created in the path where the CMD was tuned.

Comment: Perhaps a workaround, but does not answer the question

Comment: Looks like it works https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/01/onedrive-rename-remove-spaces-from-folder-name/

Comment: This is an adequate workaround for my needs, which is simply to have a path to the onedrive folder without spaces or capitalization in it.

Comment: Clean and good working solution. This answer is not appreciated enough.

Comment: Edited to clarify where you should execute the command (in home directory). Otherwise, awesome solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can change this in the registry through the following:

Find the folder name of the OneDrive synced folder in

```powershell
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}
```

Now navigate to `HKCR\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}` and change the `(Default)` string entry with the name of your choice.

This change would immediately be visible.

Comment: Doesn't work on my side

Comment: This worked fro me, but the answer is not completely clear. You need to navigate to **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\** to find the key(s) for your folders. Then you need to navigate to **HKCR\CLSID\{key-values}** and then change the default text here.

Comment: It's not working. Just to be on the same page, I read Bashan's, JW0914's, and JoeFletch comments. Seems like JoeFletch is closer, but it still didn't work and the name remained the same as it was regardless the rename in the registry keys

Answer (score 1):

@the-joatmon is 100% correct: end users confuse their private onedrive folders for the companies' folders.

It annoyed me enough that I came with an easy solution that works for me:
Hide OneDrive on the explorer left pane. To do so, use regedit --

> navigate to:
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID
> and search for: System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree
> Than change the DWORD value from 1 to 0

Then to see the effect, kill explorer in Task Manager and restart it.

Typically OneDrive syncs Documents and Pictures that are pinned to QuickAccess, so there is no reason to see them twice.

If your users have other folders that are synced, I suggest pinning them also to Quick access. Finally to cleanup I prevent Explorer from adding recently visited folders to Quick access by

> right click Quick access on left pane in explorer
> select Options and uncheck: Show frequently used folders in Quick access

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on [Oz Edri's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1559910/931977) , but with a spin:

1. Setup OneDrive , specifying a folder name that you are sure is unique inside your PC
2. Quit OneDrive
3. Rename OneDrive Folder as you desire
4. Open a registry editor and search for your unique folder. Replace every occurrence possible (you might not have permission to change some, that's fine)
5. Steps 6-8 from [Oz Edri's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1559910/931977)
6. Reboot

Comment: Worked for me, after some fiddling, on brand-new Windows 11 laptop ... and I like this solution better than fussing around with SUBST or junctions - no extra clutter. It's mystifying why Microsoft doesn't make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a "global admin" of the Office installation which gives you the business OneDrive, then changing the OneDrive root folder name is easy without changing the registry or adding filesystem links, because "Currently, updating the organization name does not update it for configured clients." (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-365/admin/manage/change-address-contact-and-more).

This means, in summary, that you can change the organization name to anything you like, call it string ***S***, trigger each OneDrive installation to use the new name, then change the organization name back to what it should be for billing, etc.

This works for me as of day of posting on my Windows 10 Pro machines, which are not associated with a Windows domain.

1. Log into Office admin center (admin.microsoft.com). Go to Settings >
   Org settings page > Organization profile tab > Organization
   information. Change the "Name" to the string  you want to use,
   and save the changes. For new OneDrive installations, your root
   OneDrive folder name is required to be "OneDrive - ***S***". Existing
   installations will NOT be changed.
2. Steps 2-4 must be done for each OneDrive root folder whose name
   should be changed (i.e., repeat for each user/machine). In OneDrive
   settings, unlink the PC. OneDrive will probably pop up a new sign-in
   window, which you can leave open.
3. In Explorer, change the root OneDrive folder name to "OneDrive -
   ***S***".
4. Return to the OneDrive sign-in window (or launch OneDrive again; or
   open another running OneDrive such as a personal OneDrive and "add
   account" in settings). Sign in with the business credentials and
   proceed to the screen which lists and confirms the location of the
   OneDrive. The default OneDrive folder root name will be your new
   name. (If you've moved the location of the OneDrive root folder, you
   may need to navigate there. Wherever it is located, the root folder
   name must be "OneDrive - ***S***".) On the next screen, you will get
   warning that the selected  location already exists and has files in
   it, and you get the choice whether to re-use the folder or create a
   new one. Choose to re-use. OneDrive will go comparing all the
   contents looking for changes. Assuming the folder was synced before
   you started and no changes in the cloud while you worked, OneDrive
   will simply count down from the total number of files to zero,
   making no changes to your local folder.
5. Go back to the online admin center and change the organization name back to
   whatever is right there. The documentation link above lists where
   that name is used across the Office environment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me (to avoid spaces and special characters) was to assign the path to the onedrive folder to a virtual disk with the command `subst` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst).

For instance: `subst O: "C:\OneDrive - <Company>"` uses the drive letter O to point to the onedrive folder in disk C.

One problem with this approach is that the mapping is temporary. It can be made permanent following [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots). However, I chose to create a shortcut to `subst O: "C:\OneDrive - <Company>"` in *C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup*.

Another minor problem is that it assigns the same label as that of the original disk. Following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-and-label-to-a-drive-letter, I removed the label (of disk C:) and added new default labels (and an icon) with the regedit keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\O\DefaultIcon]
@="%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\OneDrive\\OneDrive.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\O\DefaultLabel]
@="OneDriveCompany"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\C\DefaultLabel]
@="System"
```

Answer (score 0):

An update to [Uriel's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1512052/366290) based on advice for [creating links in Powershell for recent versions of Windows](https://winaero.com/create-symbolic-link-windows-10-powershell/):

Create a 'symbolic link' rather than a directory junction ; in Powershell, this is done using:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "NewLink" -Target "Target"
```

Answer (score -1):

#### How can I rename my personal OneDrive folder?

> The Company Name is pulled of from your Office 365 account company you
>   signed up for.  If you wanted it to be named COMPANY then change your
>   company name in Office 365.
>
> See [Change your organization's address, technical contact, and
>   more](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-organization-s-address-technical-contact-and-more-a36e5a52-4df2-479e-bb97-9e67b8483e10)

Source [[SOLVED] How can I change default name of OneDrive for Business folder? - Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1966305-how-can-i-change-default-name-of-onedrive-for-business-folder)

Comment: Well that sucks.  See my update for why.