# Opening Old & Unlinked OneDrive Folder Also Opens New OneDrive Folder in New Window

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, onedrive, microsoft, files-folders

I recently migrated from OneDrive Personal to OneDrive Business. During the process, I also performed steps [outlined here](https://superuser.com/questions/1323343/rename-onedrive-for-business-folder-in-explorer) to rename and shorten the OneDrive Business folder. Though the process was overall successful, I must have messed something up as two things currently occur:

1. Opening the old OneDrive folder triggers a new window to open for the new OneDrive Business folder.
2. While removing the 3D Objects folder (via cmd prompt process [outlined here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/remove-restore-3d-objects-on-windows-10/)), I may have somehow merged the 3D Objects folder with the new OneDrive Business folder. Or at least, opening the OneDrive Business folder shows the 3D Objects icon.

The OneDrive Business folder itself seems to be behaving as expected otherwise, but hoping to run this issue by the community here to avoid any nasty surprises down the road.