# Change the DISPLAY NAME (not the path) of a Business OneDrive folder in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, onedrive

For context: I am transgender and OneDrive for my university is showing my birth name ("deadname"), and I'd like to change it to either show my chosen name, or no name at all, just locally on my PC.
When I install OneDrive, a link appears at the top left of file explorer below "Home", and it says "`[deadname]` - `[uni name]`". And when I click on it, the address at the bar says the same thing, as shown in the picture below, censored for privacy.
[image]
What I've tried so far:

- I can customize the folder's *path* itself no problem, it doesn't contain my deadname. This is what 95% of questions I've googled for attempt to do
- I've removed OneDrive from the top of the Quick Access via the registry and re-pinned the folder itself, which doesn't show my deadname
- I've searched the entire registry and OneDrive install folder for my deadname, to no avail.
- I've used `desktop.ini` to attempt to rename the folder, which does rename my custom pin, as seen in the picture ("uni abbreviation") but doesn't affect the name in the File Explorer address bar
- My uni Microsoft account and its email already are in my chosen name, but I had to get it changed to get there and I sometimes still see my deadname initials before my pfp loads so I think my deadname is still in the system somehow?
- I've opened a ticket with my uni IT but just in case they can't do anything, I'm opening this thread
- I've made symlinks using Powershell and `subst`, but these confuse Windows and make it forget that it's OneDrive, leading to weird artifacts like MS Word asking to save a file created in OneDrive... to OneDrive

All I need is for the folder itself to say something different *on my computer*. I literally don't care what registry tweak or program or hack or whatever, I just don't want to see my deadname.

Comment: Here are some interesting answers about that but I'm not sure any of these actually work: https://superuser.com/questions/1323343/rename-onedrive-for-business-folder-in-explorer

Comment: Tried all of those answers but nothing worked unfortunately.